# Handler postDelayed - print every second something

Tags: android, video, handler, android-camera2

I want to print the current second using a `handler`. I record a video for exactly `10 seconds` and want to set the text of a `TextView` every second.

Recording 10 seconds works like that:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
           stopRecordingVideo();
    }
}, 11000);  // don't know why 11000 but it only works this way
```

After the 10 seconds the method `stopRecordingVideo()` gets executed. So how can  I change the text every second of the TextView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working answer:

```
int t = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        t++;
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.formatted_time, t));
        if(t<10) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Where formatted_time is something like that:

`<string android:name="formatted_time">%d seconds</string>`

Comment: I had to declare t as a final int[], but after tis change it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To print text every second, you can use [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). But if you want to achieve this with try below code:

```
void startTime(){
    //Post handler after 1 second.
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}

int totalDelay=0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        totalDelay++;   
        if(totalDelay<=10){
            //If total time is less then 10 second execute handler again after 1 second
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
        textView.setText(totalDelay+" Second");
    }
};
```

Comment: Why is here a startTime method? I don't really need it right?

Comment: yes, just call "handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);" to start timer.

Comment: But in my case, when should I call `StopRecordingVideo`? Just beneath this piece of code?

Comment: if(totalDelay<=10){
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}else{stopRecordingVideo() }

Comment: Hm doesn't work for me. `Variable 'runnable' initializer 'new Runnable() { @Override pu.." is redunant` and the code is grey

Comment: put this code at class level. dont put this code inside method.

Comment: But I need this code after a button click and so it has to be in a method

Comment: No. just put 'handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);' in your buttton click.

Comment: 'handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);' will execute runnable after 1 second. and untill totalDelay is less than 10 second execute the above statement repeatedly.

Comment: Does this execute same thread of create another thread in next execute?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, basically do the increment in a worker thread, but updating the text view is done by main's thread handler.

```
 Thread worker= new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               try {
                  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
             // stop recording after 10 seconds
               if (i == 9) {

                  handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                        stopRecordingVideo();
                     }
                  });
               }

              else{
                   // set text for each second
                  handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                        textView.setText(String.valueOf(i+1));
                     }
                  });

               }
            }//ends for()

     worker.start()
```